# Behavioral modification software to improve discipline

Tags: windows, android, productivity, parental-control

I am at my wits and with my seeming incapability to change my behaviors for the better. Self-help requires the will and motivation to change, and while I have an intellectual understanding of the problems that my inability to delay gratification, impatience are persisting on long-term changes in goals, and inability to form new habits, I'd be lying if I said that I had any emotional energy or motivation to change. However, I think that shaping my environment and deliberately handing my little-used-anyway locus of control to something designed to force me into behaviors - implementing things that make me incapable of not doing something, as opposed to things that ask me to do something - until such time as I am accustomed enough to them and/or mentally healthy enough to responsibly reclaim my locus works just as well, if not better.

To that end, what I am looking for is threefold. I am looking for features that will box in my behavior on my computer and online that someone else can set a password on that even a Windows power user would be unable to disable, well as an equivalent for my phone. unfortunately, some of the software that I need to use on a semi-daily basis requires administrator rights, else this would have been easily solved by myself long ago by just assigning myself to a limited user and have somebody else create an administrative account and put parental control locks on my user, preferably someone that knows how to set group policies. I've set a scheduled task to force shutdown my computer after 11pm and if it is turned on at all before 6am, and set login times using net shell as a backup, and I used the parental controls on my cable modem/router to block sites on my computer and had my wife change the password, but any new phones or computers in the house also get blocked and she doesn't know how to unblock them. Not a great system so far.

I'm also looking for an equivalent for my phone that does not require root, as I have cryptocurrency trading software on it, and because T-Mobile forsakes all customers who root. But if I have to, I will.

Third, if such a thing exists, something that can take this out into my offline life, life a support group software where people can fine me for not doing something and showing evidence, or something to the effect of seeing detrimental consequences for inaction. Or that could link me up with someone local to ride my laziness-associated body part. My wife doesn't have the time or patience to police my behavior, nor should she. I don't really have any friends, and my church congregants are uninterested. Normally I have my job to structure my time, but I'm off on medical leave following a hip surgery and that anchor is gone.

If there are a Linux solution I'd try that, except something about my setup leaves live CDs and USBs frozen and install CDs and USBs frozen at install, no matter the failsafe arguments I use or the distros, Debian, red hat, even FreeBSD, but this is a conversation for another site.

My pc is custom build windows 10x64, my phone is a Galaxy S7 T-Mobile with stock Android 7